# Running Matlab code on a cluster

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, cluster-computing

I have a university account for the university's cluster, but I don't know how can I use it to run my Matlab code. Could anyone help? I connect to the cluster by typing below code in the terminal of my laptop:

```
ssh myusername@192.168.194.222
```

Then it asks me to type my password.After that, below text appears:

```
Welcome to gav 9.1.1 (3.12.60-ql-generic-9.1-74) based on Ubuntu     14.04.5 LTS
Last login: Sun Apr 16 10:45:49 2017 from 192.168.41.213
gav:~ >
```

How can I run my code after these processes? Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a Linux shell, so you can run your script (for instance yourScript.m)

```
> matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash < yourScript.m
```

(see also https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html)

Comment: -bash: test.m: No such file or directory Ths is the output

Comment: @OliverRange are you trying to run the script `test.m`? Have you copied it to the remote machine?

Comment: Yes I want to run test.m code. But no, how can I copy it to the remote machine?!

Comment: @OliverRange if you have `ssh` you should also have `scp` (secure copy)

Comment: after login, should I type scp test.m ?

Comment: @OliverRange you should run `scp` from your local machine

Comment: just run scp in the terminal?

Comment: You run `scp LOCALFILENAME USERNAME@192.168.194.222:REMOTEFILENAME` Replace the words in capital letters. Note that you can get help on any UNIX command by writing `--help` after the command, like `scp --help`

Comment: Also (just in case): Do not type out the leading `>` which @user2314737 wrote in his answer. This is just to indicate that the following text shall be written in a shell prompt (as opposed to quoting for example text in a configuration file)

Comment: I have another question about saving videos on my laptop from the result of the code which has been run in the cluster. Should I start a new question or its better to ask here?

Comment: Better start a new one. Also note that you can reverse the order of `scp` arguments to download instead of upload. Also, there is help on `scp` on the internet; google "how to use scp" or similar.

Comment: I need your help again. When I run my code in the cluster, there are errors in lines containing graphical things such as igure, plot, video ... . This is an error related to the figure (forexample): Error using figure
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Comment: How can I solve this problem and save videos and fugures?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are two possibilities:

- Conventional Matlab is installed on the Cluster
- The Matlab Distributed Computing server is installed on the cluster

## Conventional Matlab is installed on the Cluster

You execute Matlab on the cluster as you would on your local computer. <strike>I guess that you work on Windows on your local computer, given that you quote a simple shell prompt in your question ;)</strike> *All right, all right, bad psychic skillz ;) see edit below*.

What you see is the cluster awaiting a program name to execute. This is called the "Shell". Google "Linux shell tutorial" or [start with this tutorial](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php) to get information about how to operate a Linux system without a graphical desktop.

Try to start matlab by simply typing `matlab` after the text you've seen. If it works, you see Matlab's welcome message and the Matlab prompt as you would see it in Matlab's command window on your local PC.

**Bonus:** you can try to execute Matlab on the cluster but see a graphical interface by replacing your `ssh` call by `ssh -X myusername@192.168.194.222`, so add an additional `-X`.

Upload your Matlab scripts to the cluster, for example by using WinSCP ([tutorial](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_upload))

Execute your Matlab functions like you would locally by navigating into the correct folder and typing the function name.

**EDIT:** As you use Linux, you may use `gio mount ssh://myusername@192.168.194.222` to access your home folder on the cluster via your file manager. If that fails, try `gvfs-mount ssh://myusername@192.168.194.222` (the old name of the tool). The packages `gvfs-backends` and `gvfs-fuse` (I assume that you use ubuntu, other distributions may have different package names) must be installed for this; use your Package manager to install them if you get an error like "command not found".

## Distributed Computing Server

This provides a set of Matlab "Workers" which are sent tasks from your local Computer. You use your local Matlab installation to connect to the Distributed computing server.  Start with the [Matlab Help Pages for the Distributed Computing Server](https://de.mathworks.com/help/mdce/getting-started.html)

Comment: Actually, I use linux

Comment: After login, When I type matlab on terminal the output is -bash: matlab: command not found

Comment: gvfs-fuse and gvfs-backends are both installed but the output for gio mount ssh://myusername@192.168.194.222 and  gvfs-mount ssh://myusername@192.168.194.222 is command not found

Comment: oh, sorry, the wiki I had the information from was apparently outdated. [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) tells me that the package `gvfs-bin` is needed as well.

Comment: As you have a `command not found` error when executing Matlab, are you sure that Matlab is installed on the Cluster? It must be installed on both your local computer and the cluster. Try to execute `locate matlab` on the cluster and see if you get a large list of files belonging to matlab.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it is installed.

Comment: when I use scp test  username@192.168.194.222 the output is
cp: cannot stat 'test': No such file or directory. do you know where is the problem?

Comment: "cannot stat" is an unfortunate UNIX jargon for "cannot find". So it can not find a file called "test". Make sure the file name is written correctly and you are in the correct folder with your shell. Type `pwd` to get your current working directory. Type `ls` to list the contents of the current directory. Use the TAB key to auto-complete file names you type in.

Comment: when I type pwd in terminal, the output is a place n the cluster. How can I tell it that I want to copy the program from my laptop?!

Comment: If you are sure that Matlab is installed on the cluster but you nevertheless get a "command not found" when calling `matlab`, then the cluster system does not know where to look for the Matlab executable. Ask your Administrator in which folder Matlab is installed. Then, use the whole path to execute matlab, and replace `matlab` in @user2314737 's answer by the complete path.

Comment: you have to execute the `scp` command on your local laptop, not on the cluster. Open up a terminal on your local computer and invoke `scp` from there. It's easier to copy files graphically, [see this SO question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4625/is-there-a-gui-utility-to-mount-remote-filesystems-over-ssh)